# Ruby UDP server/client test fails

Tags: ruby, udp

I am trying to setup a simple UDP client and server using Ruby. The code looks like this:

```
require 'socket.so'

class UDPServer
  def initialize(port)
    @port = port
  end

  def start
    @socket = UDPSocket.new
    @socket.bind(nil, @port) # is nil OK here?
    while true
      packet = @socket.recvfrom(1024)
      puts packet
    end
  end
end

server = UDPServer.new(4321)
server.start
```

This is the client:

```
require 'socket.so'

class UDPClient
  def initialize(host, port)
    @host = host
    @port = port
  end

  def start
    @socket = UDPSocket.open
    @socket.connect(@host, @port)
    while true
      @socket.send("otiro", 0, @host, @port)
      sleep 2
    end
  end
end

client = UDPClient.new("10.10.129.139", 4321) # 10.10.129.139 is the IP of UDP server
client.start
```

Now, I have two VirtualBox machines running Linux. They are in the same network, they can ping to each other.

But when I start the UDP server on machine A, and then try to run the UDP client on machine B I get the following error:

```
client.rb:13:in `send': Connection refused - sendto(2) (Errno::ECONNREFUSED)
```

I suspect that the error is in the bind method on the server. I don't know which address I should specify there. I read somewhere that you should use the address of your LAN/WAN interface, but I don't how to obtain that address.

Can anyone help me with this one?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your host parameter `nil` is understood as *localhost*, so an external machine won't be able to connect to that socket.  Try this instead:

```
@socket.bind('', @port) # '' ==> INADDR_ANY
```

From the docs for [Socket](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Socket.html):

> host is a host name or an address string (dotted decimal for IPv4, or a
>   hex string for IPv6) for which to
>   return information. A nil is also
>   allowed, its meaning depends on flags,
>   see below.
>
> ....
>
> Socket::AI_PASSIVE: when set, if host is nil the ‘any’ address will be
>   returned, Socket::INADDR_ANY or 0 for
>   IPv4, "0::0" or "::" for IPv6. This
>   address is suitable for use by servers
>   that will bind their socket and do a
>   passive listen, thus the name of the
>   flag. Otherwise the local or loopback
>   address will be returned, this is
>   "127.0.0.1" for IPv4 and "::1’ for
>   IPv6

Comment: Using '' or Socket::INADDR_ANY as IP address for the bind method fixes the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Is `@socket.bind("10.10.129.139", @port)` in the server not working?

Edit:

Usually you could have multiple network interfaces on one machine (WLAN, LAN, ..). They all have different IP addresses, so you have to bind a server to at least one host address.